# Take Specific Cells from Multiple Sheets in Excel with VBA to same PDF Workbook

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I have created the code I need to export the data from excel to PDF, however I am at a loss on how to get them in the same workbook on separate pages. I can get the two sheets into the same workbook, however not when I am selecting specific cells.

Here is a sample of what I am doing. Granted, this has an error right now as I am working on getting the data into one PDF, etc.

I am sure it is an easy fix, just not sure where to go with it. Right now my error is in the section where I am selecting ranges.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub PDF_Creator()
'
' PDF_Creator Macro
' Creates PDF pages for specific Excel Sheets.
'

'
    Sheets(Array("Servicer Recon", "Delq Summary")).Select
    **Range(Array("A1:B6","A3:I15)).Select**
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\jnielsen\Desktop\ServicerStatus-SST.pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Sheets("Delq Summary").Select
    Range("A4:I15").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem statement is: `Range(Array("A1:B6", "A3:I15)).Select`

Problem 1: There is a missing double quote at the end of the second range.  It should be `"A3:I15"`.

Problem 2: You cannot combine ranges in this way.  Try:

```
Union(Range("A1:B6"), Range("A3:I15")).Select
```

I use an old version of Excel and cannot comment on your use of ExportAsFixedFormat.